# Как в Linux посчитать загрузку на процессор самому?

Tags: linux, debian, процессор

Как в Linux читая данные из `/proc` можно определить загрузку ЦП, какие поля и данные нужно брать и как это считает?
В гугле находил что-то подобное, но было невнятно и особо не помогло.

Comment: Посмотрите в исходниках top, например. Он входит в пакет procps https://github.com/soarpenguin/procps-3.0.5

Comment: `cat /proc/stat`, затем `man proc`, откуда узнаем `user   (1) Time spent in user mode. nice   (2) Time spent in user mode with low priority (nice). system (3) Time spent in system mode. idle   (4) Time spent in the idle task`. Значит берем 1+2+3 / 4 - получаем загрузку, если нужно в процентах, домножаем на 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решил так (код на C#):

```
static Regex _regRmSpaces = new Regex(@"\s+");

static long _idleOld = 0;
static long _totalOld = 0;

public static float GetCpuUsagePercent() {
    string line = null;
    try {
      using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("/proc/stat", FileMode.Open)) {
            using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream)) {
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) return 9999;

                line = _regRmSpaces.Replace(line, " ");
                var columns = line.Split(' ');

                long[] data = new long[columns.Length - 1];
                for (int i = 1; i < columns.Length; i++) {
                    data[i - 1] = long.Parse(columns[i].Trim());
                }

                long total = data[0] + data[1] + data[2] + data[3]
                        + data[4] + data[5] + data[6] + data[7];
                long idle = data[3];

                float del_idle = idle - _idleOld;
                float del_total = total - _totalOld;

                float result = 100 * ((del_total - del_idle) / del_total);

                _idleOld = idle;
                _totalOld = total;

                return result;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ProcessLog.Error(e);
    }
    return 9999;
}
```